# Analyzing the complexity of a number in the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, serial, communication, programming, math

I'm working on a project where I'm linking a calculator (TI-84) to an Arduino (Nano) and I want some way of classifying or quantifying how complex a single number is (small whole numbers being very simple, irrational numbers being the most complex).

I don't need it to be a perfect or even a direct/linear map, but the closer the better. Speed of computation is more important in this case.

I was thinking of just counting the number of digits, but I want 1.333333 to be classified as less complex than 1.245682. Also 12,345 should be less complex than 12,973 but more complex than 12,000.

Any ideas?

Comment: Such a thing may exist, but that's not an electronics question, and you would need to explain why would some number be more "complex" than some other number.

Comment: @Justme apologies, this would be using the mathematical definition of complexity.

Comment: Anyway, it's a purely mathematical question. You can't have irrational numbers in MCUs unless you code them yourself, you only get floats and doubles that are standard. In computer memory they are just finite length bit strings approximating the value given a range, so with floats you can't even represent all integers larger than 16777216 as you don't have the precision to do that. With floats or doubles, you can't even represent 0.1 exactly, only an approximation of it.

Comment: @LilMamiChula What is the referenced mathematical definition of complexity? I've encountered some. But none of those fit here. Also, given you are on the path of being (or are) a mathematician, I assume you are aware that irrationals are infinitely more prevalent than rationals. Regardless, continued fractions come unbidden to mind when talking complexity, as *every irrational number is represented in precisely one way as an infinite simple continued fraction.* (See docs at the Wolfram site for more.) Still would like to know what ***you*** mean, though.

Comment: Agree, not really an electronics question. Math or CS would be more topical?

Comment: @LilMamiChula For example, is the continued fraction \$\left[1; \overline{2}\right]=\sqrt{2}\$ more or less complex than \$\left[1; 1,1,2\right]=\frac35=0.6\$? Is \$\frac35\$ more or less complex than \$\left[0; 7\right]=\frac17=0.\overline{142857}\$? The latter is shorter in continued fraction form. But in decimal form it is an infinite repeated group of digits. You really do need to define your terms more precisely. Otherwise, it looks like hand-waving (*"I'll know complexity when I see it"*) kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't represent irrational numbers in a computer unless you use some form of symbolic language or formalism. All numerical representations inside a computer are inherently rationale.

All rational numbers can be represented as the ratio of two integers, i.e.

\$ x = \frac{p}{q}, x \in \mathbb{Q}, p,q \in \mathbb{Z} \$

This can be used to derive a complexity metric. We can assume that p and q are mutually prime and we can break both down into their prime factors. Complexity could be based on number and/or magnitude of the prime factors.

For example

\$1.3333333... = \frac{4}{3} \\
1.245682 = \frac{103 \cdot 6047}{2^5\cdot 5^5}\$

Answer (score 1):

Any number that is representable can be measured in terms of information, e.g. Shannon entropy.

First, you may want a variable-length encoding so that e.g. 1 and one million have different sizes.  Whereas int32 takes up 32 bits regardless of the value in its range, one or a million.

You might also want a variable number of digits, so more precise values require more bits; or more components thereof, so that for example rational numbers take two integers, complex rationals take three or four, etc.  Each component might be representable with variable-length or variable-precision as above.

Or you might store numbers as factors, with more factors, or exponents thereof, adding to the information count.  Depends if you want a more number-theoretic or colloquial (decimals are trivial shifts?) sort of measure.

(There's a number coding scheme along these lines that's well known for number-theoretic purposes but I cannot remember the name associated with it, and Google is astonishingly useless to find it. If someone can comment what I'm thinking of, that will help.)

You can apply these principles recursively as far as you like.  Irrational numbers are easily represented symbolically.  The set of irrationals is built by an adjoining process: take a root of any rational number, and add those to the set.  Add sums and differences to the set so it is complete (the result of any operation (+, -, *, /) on a number in the set must also be in the set).  Then take roots of those differences, and so on infinitely.

Note this exactly misses the algebraic numbers, numbers whose only description is as the solution to an algebraic equation -- roots do not give complete coverage for all possible roots. (This is another consequence of the unsolvable quintic.)

We can continue the process further, describing algorithms or automata to compute numbers.  Eventually, we can cover all possible computable numbers within a given amount of information.  This includes such simple transcendentals as π, but also a variety of uninteresting ones, like values of the Lambert W function.

At some point, one would rightfully ask, what's the point of such representations?  How can you do work with them?  Indeed, eventually we find numbers that can only be described in such arcane ways that, while they have a position on the real number line, there's absolutely nothing interesting to do with them, they simply exist to fill space (and this is no accident, as the reals are a very, *very* dense set indeed).  Transcendentals like π are wonderful because they show up everywhere, and thus have useful properties to manipulate between a massive range of equations.  But these are few indeed (there's what, π, e, maybe γ, and not much else that's nearly as useful -- a subjective ranking to be sure, but one could imagine criteria could be widely agreed upon and a rank determined as a result).

So, it depends what you want to do with it.  An arbitrarily complex system might be extraordinarily expressive, but meaningless for manipulation purposes.

Further keywords -- I've also come all this way and haven't even name-dropped Kolmogorov complexity.  This doesn't really have a measure -- imagine solving the halting problem -- but that said, think Code Golf for theory.  There might always be a more optimal description of a number, but how close can we get given our limited resources?